# How to format grep results?

Tags: bash, grep

Wow, I could not think of a good way to title this question.  Basically I have a file called "attendance" with data like this:

```
11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName
11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName
11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName
11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName
```

Basically it's the date, IP address, First name, and Last name.  The above is how it is formatted in the "attendance" file.  I have created an html page with text boxes and a submit button where a user can either:  A.) Enter a FN/LN and receive a list of dates that person logged in, OR B.) Type in a date and receive a list of users who logged in on that date.

I'm getting the results I want, but the result of the grep displayed in the browser is all on one line, like this:

```
11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName 11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName 11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName 11/06/2014 101.11.001.01 FirstName LastName
```

Obviously this is sub-optimal.  I need the grep results to appear on separate lines.  Below is my .cgi file. "getvars" is just a script the professor made for converting variable types. Also, I'm cutting corners by only grepping last name, because nobody has the same last name:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/bin/getvars

if [ ! -z "$LN" ]; then
cat attendance | grep $LN

elif [ ! -z "$DATE" ]; then
cat attendance | grep $DATE

else echo No Records Found

fi
```

I've tried to be as concise as possible and I apologize is anything doesn't make sense.  My only question is:  How do I get the grep results on separate lines?

Comment: hm, when I test it in a shell it shows up on different lines as expected.. Even when I redirect it into a file. I'm guessing either you have something odd with your grep (unlikely I'd think) or the way you display the text is doing it..

Comment: What is the name of the file you are saving the lines in? Does it have an html extension?

Comment: Seth - Yes, I did the same grep just in the shell and it looked fine, until its out to the browser

Comment: You need to add <br> between each line. Also need to change all occurrences of & < > to their HTML entity equivalents.

Comment: I think Mark might be correct, when you pass grep's output into the webpage (I'm assuming it is HTML) the linebreaks aren't necessarily going to be preserved.

Comment: Mark - I was thinking that could be a good idea...but the "attendance" file is actually created from data from all of the users - We each have a personal login text file with our own logins, then we each have a script to append each user's most recent login to the "attendance" script.  Wouldn't each user have to append <br>?  If so, that would be impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your browser is interpreting whatever file you're pointing it to as HTML. In HTML a newline is not `\n` but the `<br>` tag, so you would need to add that. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. ~/bin/getvars

if [ ! -z "$LN" ]; then
  grep "$LN" attendance | sed 's/$/<br>/'
elif [ ! -z "$DATE" ]; then
  grep "$DATE" attendance | sed 's/$/<br>/'
else 
   echo No Records Found
fi
```

On my Debian, firefox interprets `\n` as line breaks if the file has no `.html` extension (I tried with no extension and `.txt`) so that might be a workaround but I have no idea how portable that would be.

A better alternative would be to make it a proper HTML page, use `<pre>` tags and replace all `<` and `>` with their HTML equivalents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. ~/bin/getvars

echo "<HTML><BODY><pre>"
if [ ! -z "$LN" ]; then
  grep "$LN" attendance | sed 's/>/\&gt;/g;s/</\&lt;/g;'
elif [ ! -z "$DATE" ]; then
  grep "$DATE" attendance | sed 's/>/\&gt;/g;s/</\&lt;/g;'
else 
   echo No Records Found
fi
echo "</pre></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Wow!  thank you terdon.  That worked.  We talked about "sed" in class, but it's still mystifying to me.  It seems to be pretty useful.

Comment: @Shane yes, `sed` is very powerful. Have a look through some of the [tag:sed] Q&As. What I'm using here is the substitution operator, general syntax: `s/foo/bar/` which will change `foo` to `bar`. The `/g` in the answer makes it replace all occurrences in the line. The `&` is a special character for sed (it means "whatever I just matched") so I need to escape it (`\&`).

Comment: you really do not need to even call grep in your case. sed is a pattern matching/replacing tool. It can do a lot of very cool things. check this link out http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html be be on your way to greatness :) It also goes over another really powerful tool called awk. enjoy.

Comment: @terdon If `sed` used there is no need to use `grep`? Just propose: `sed -n '/$var/{s/>/\&gt;/g;s/</\&lt;/g;p}'`. Secondary if we do the same operations may be it will be better to use `for var in "$LN" "$DATE"`?

Comment: @Costas yes, I know I don't need `grep` (I don't know why you felt you had to repeat that, didn't you see Rob's comment?). I don't need sed either, I could have done the whole thing in `perl` or `awk`. Hell, I could have done it all in a bash while loop. However, I try to keep to the OP's code as much as possible because i) I don't know their level of understanding and want my answer to be understood and ii) this may be just a simplified example. Personally, I would have done this as you suggest but... Oh, and you would need double quotes on your `sed` for it to work.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for answer and correction. I didn't try to check your knowlege but in opposite try to study your decision and to understand why you use this way to settle task. As you can see I am newbie here and just try to find out is there some hidden from me sense to do so by respect members of the service. Sorry if made you angry.